How can I do these graphics in tikz?

This is how I did the little retangle.
Is there any simpler package that I could use to do these graphics?
\documentclass{article}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, calc, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
% Adapted from the 'patterns' library: enlarged the distance between the lines from 4pt to 10pt
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{north east lines wide}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{10pt}{10pt}}{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{9.1pt}{9.1pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}


\tikzset{%
    body/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,shape=rectangle,draw,thick},
    dimen/.style={<->,>=latex,thin,every rectangle node/.style={fill=white,midway,font=\sffamily}},
    symmetry/.style={dashed,thin},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5] % Reduz o tamanho geral do gráfico

    % Retângulo centrado no eixo
    \node [body,minimum height=1.25cm,minimum width=5cm,anchor=center] (body1) at (0,0) {};

    % Eixos
    \draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,4) node[right] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (6,0) -- (-7,0) node[above] {$z$};

    % Força Vy em vermelho
    \draw[->, thick, red] (0,3) -- (0,0) node[above, right] {$V_y$};

    % Força Vz em vermelho
    \draw[->, thick, red] (4.5,0) -- (0,0);
    \node [text=red, label={[xshift=0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]$V_z$}] {};

    
    % A body
    
    % Dimensions
    \draw (body1.south east) -- ++(1.5,0) coordinate (D1) -- +(-5pt,0);
    \draw (body1.north east) -- ++(1.5,0) coordinate (D2) -- +(-5pt,0);
    \draw [dimen] (D1) -- (D2) node {4.00};
    % Helper nodes can be reused
    \draw (body1.south west) -- ++(0,-2) coordinate (D1) -- +(0,-5pt);
    \draw (body1.south east) -- ++(0,-2) coordinate (D2) -- +(0,-5pt);
    \draw [dimen] (D1) -- (D2) node {1.50};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}



Any help is greatly appreciated!

It might be difficult to provide examples for several diagrams. Could you potentially ask about some diagrams individually, and then we can provide focused responses?

maybe the first in the second picture, i think that one is the hardest, isnt it? I don't know how to make any of those, can you check the one i did and tell me how can i position the nodes better? thank you so much in advance

If you narrowed the question down to just a picture of that picture, plus a reasonable attempt of your own, I am sure people would be more inclined to help out. Think about it, just a few small modifications will help you reach your answer more effectively.

I can't really tell from this what you're having trouble doing. there's just a whole bunch of handwritten stuff, several sketches and some code. what does the code relate to and what's the problem with it? if you know how to define custom patterns, you should be able to do most of this, I would think?

The more powerful a packge is, the more difficult it is to learn how to use it.  I would avoid custom patterns if possible.

For a possible solution for the first picture of the second page (which you seem to have the most difficulties with) you could make use of the calc library (I left away the labels in the below code).
Note that the order of the transformations of the scope is crucial: rotate around={-5:(0,0)}, shift={(4,0)}. We first want to rotate around the origin of the original picture and only then shift the result 4cm to the right (within the rotated coordinate system).
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]

    \coordinate (A) at (2,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (-2,-1);
    \draw (A) rectangle (B);

    \draw[->] (.5,0) -- (-3,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,2);

    \begin{scope}[rotate around={-5:(0,0)}, shift={(4,0)}]
        \draw[->] (-5,0) -- (2,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (0,-2);
        \coordinate (D) at (0,2);
        \draw[->] (C) -- (D);

        \coordinate (E) at ($(C)!(A)!(D)$);
        \coordinate (F) at ($(C)!(B)!(D)$);
    
        \draw[dashed] (A) -- (E) -- ($(E)!-1cm!(A)$);
        \draw[dashed] (B) -- (F) -- ($(F)!-1cm!(B)$);
    
        \draw (E) -- ($(E)!-.5cm!(A)$) -- 
            ($(F)!.5cm!(B)$) -- (F);
    
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
            \draw[->] ($(0,0)!\i*1/6!(E)$) -- +({\i*1/6*.5cm},0);
            \draw[->] ($(0,0)!\i*1/6!(F)$) -- +({\i*1/6*-.5cm},0);
        }
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Here, I used the following syntaxes:

($(C)!(A)!(D)$) means: coordinate of the orthogonal projection of (A) onto the line from (C) to (D).
($(E)!-1cm!(A)$) means: coordinate at the distance of -1cm between (E) and (A) (which due to the negative value lies outside the given segment, more exactly 1cm away from (E) in the opposite direction of (A)).

